# Using {{#link-to}} within {{#each}} with a parent template variable in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to generalize a component which occurs a number of times throughout our UI.

There is a variable `item-type` which is passed into the component and currently I'm trying to use it like so:

```
{{#each items}}
    {{#link-to ../item-type this ...}}...{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

I get this error:

> This link-to is in an inactive loading state because at least one of its parameters presently has a null/undefined value, or the provided route name is invalid.

However, logging the variable works fine:

```
{{#each items}}
    {{log ../item-type}}
{{/each}}
```

Of course, if I exchange `../item-type` with its value (hardcoded) it works fine.

Does `link-to` not support this handlebars macro?

If not, is there an alternative binding that can be done with a handlebar helper?

Comment: What's the '../' for?

Comment: @chopper http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths "Nested handlebars paths can also include ../ segments, which evaluate their paths against a parent context."

Comment: Ah I see. You never stop learning.. :)

Comment: Where do you get ../item-type from? Do you pass it to the parent?

Comment: Yeah, it's passed to the component (which in this case is the parent). `../` is necessary since `{{#each}}` gives the block a new context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up solving it by binding the parent context using a `{{#with}}`.

I can't imagine this is the suggested method, so I'll leave the question open if anyone who knows the real answer comes around.

Example:

```
{{#with this as component}}
    {{#each items}}
        {{#link-to component.item-type this ..}}...{{/link-to}}
    {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

Edit: It's been nearly 2 years and this is still listed in the Ember team's spreadsheet of unresolved SO bugs. I'm going to close it now.

Comment: Yeah would also like to know this, as I stumbled upon the same problem while creating components inside a each loop